# Encode/Decode SEO urls through platform API?

Tags: joomla, seo, friendly-url

I am trying to decode and encode Joomla urls but Joomla doesn't seem to have a consistent API for that (how it looks). The main problem comes in when another SEO plugin is installed and the operation is performed as background process (ie: not whilst rendering in a browser through Joomla).

The other big problem is that users copy and paste SEO urls of the own site directly into the content.

Does anyone knows a solution for this ? Supporting all sorts of SEO plugins individually is a total no-go and rather impossible.

I actually thought its the Job of the CMS to guarantee on a API level that SEO urls can be decoded and encoded without knowing the plugins, but no. I also had a look in some plugins and indeed, plugins do 
handle code for other plugins whilst it shouldn't be, coz.

Well,
thanks

Comment: Are you referring to something like https://groups.google.com/d/msg/joomla-dev-cms/GDhSTee_uwE/Be-eaum4JdEJ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. JRoute won't work reliably in the administrator, I even tried hacking it, it's a no-go.

Moveover sh404 (one of the leading SEF extensions) does a curl call to the frontend in order to get the paths right. You can find in their code a commented attempt to route in the backend.

Are you are trying to parse content when it's saved, find SEF urls and replace with their non-sef equivalents?  If you create a simple component to handle this in the frontend (just get what you need from xmap), then you can query the frontend from the backend with curl/wget and possibly achieve this with a decent rate of success: but I wouldn't expect this to work 100% (sometimes parameters are added by components, or the order of parameters is different from call to call, and the router.php in extensions can be very fragile or even plain wrong).